# print within function gives correct value, but the return gives zero?

Tags: c, return

I've been trying to return the "hypo" and I can get the correct value to print within the function but when I try to use the return value of hypo outside of the function it is returning zero. Any reason why?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double pythagorean(double num1, double num2);

int main() {
    //----------------------------------------------------------------- Problem 1
    double a;
    double b;
    double hypo;
  
    printf("Enter the value for a: ");  //values for A and B
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    printf("Enter the value for b: ");
    scanf("%lf", &b);
    
    pythagorean(a, b);                    // function one
  
    printf("If a = %.3lf and b = %.3lf, then that means the hypotenuse is %.3lf.\n", a, b, hypo);
    
    return 0;
}

double pythagorean(double num1, double num2)
{
    double hypo = sqrt((num1) * (num1) + (num2) * (num2));
    printf("%lf\n", hypo);  
    
    return hypo;
}
```

Comment: Where in `main` do you set `hypo`?

Comment: Try `hypo = pythagorean(a,b);` to actually use the return value. The variables may share a name but they are completely different variables in different scopes.

Comment: Also, when attempting to check your code, it was necessary to add "math.h" to the include list as well as add library "m" to the compile and linking parameters within the IDE.

Comment: I have the math.h and library, just didnt include it here :p

Comment: Enable your compiler's warnings! It would have caught this error. With gcc and clang, you could use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: Also, see [**7.12.7.3 The hypot functions**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.7.3)

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
pythagorean(a,b);
```

to

```
hypo = pythagorean(a,b);  // store the return value in 'hypo'
```

Just because the variable names are same, since they reside in different scope, they do not share the same memory , and/or get updated automatically.

Alternatively, for simple cases like this one, you can actually do away with the hassle of storing the return value, and print it directly, with something like:

```
printf("If a = %.3lf and b = %.3lf, <abcdefgh....> %.3lf.\n", a, b, pythagorean(a,b));
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                     use direct function call.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store the return value of the `pythagorean` function call into the `hypo` local variable in `main()`:

```
    hypo = pythagorean(a, b);
```

Also note these remarks:

- you should test the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid or missing input.
- you should use the library function `hypot()` that computes the hypotenuse with better precision in corner cases (no pun intended).

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double pythagorean(double num1, double num2);

int main() {
    //----------------------------------------------------------------- Problem 1
    double a;
    double b;
    double hypo;
  
    printf("Enter the value for a: ");  //values for A and B
    if (scanf("%lf", &a) != 1)
        return 1;
    printf("Enter the value for b: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &b) != 1)
        return 1;
    
    hypo = pythagorean(a, b);                    // function one
  
    printf("If a = %.3f and b = %.3f, then that means the hypotenuse is %.3f.\n", a, b, hypo);
    printf("using pythagorean: %17g, using hypot: %17g\n", hypo, hypot(a, b));

    return 0;
}

double pythagorean(double num1, double num2)
{
    double hypo = sqrt(num1 * num1 + num2 * num2);
    return hypo;
}
```